# Arrival Steering Behavior stop before reaching evader

Tags: steering-behaviors

Im doing steering behaviors and trying to stop before reaching the evader. Instead of reaching the evader at its center, I need it to stop before. I cant seem to figure this out though. My code is below from Programming Game AI by Example by Buckland.

```
Vector3 Arrive(Vector3 target, deceleration decel)
{



    Vector3 totarget = evader->target - vehicle->cp;

     //calcualte the distance to the target position
    float dist = totarget.Length();

if(dist > 0.0f)
{
    //because deceleration is enumerated as an int, this value is require to provide fine tweaking of the deceleration
const float decelerationtweaker = 0.3f;

//calculate the speed require to reach the target given the desired deceleration
float speed = dist / ((float)decel * decelerationtweaker);

//make sure the velcoity does not excceed the max
speed = min(speed, 5); //maxspeed


//frome here proceed just liek seek except we dont need to nomalize the totarget vector because we have already gone to the trouble of calculating its lenght: dist
 Vector3 vecDesired = totarget * speed / dist;

 return (DesiredVelocity - vehicle->Velocity);
}

    return Vector3(0,0,0);

}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem, what did you try that didn't work? If you want it to stop 3 meters from the target, why not just decrease dist by 3 meters?